# Ignore all elements not present in the test XML with XMLUnit

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit, xmlunit-2

In XMLUnit 2.x, can I ignore all elements in the actual ("control") XML that are not present in my test ("expected") XML?

**Example:**

Actual:

```
<a>123</a>
<b>456</b>
<c>789</c>
```

Test:

```
<b>456</b>
<c>xxx</c>
```

I would want to detect the difference in `<c>` but ignore the `<a>` tag completely because it's not present in the test XML.

The idea is that I have a big XML that I want to compare, but only a subset of elements is interesting to me, and I don't want to give XMLUnit a still large list of element names to ignore or to not ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own `DifferenceEvaluator` and return `ComparisonResult.SIMILAR` (or even `EQUAL`) on all `CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH` and `CHILD_LOOKUP` comparisons.

If you only want to ignore elements added in your test document (rather than ignore all elements not present on the other side independent of direction) then you should only downgrade `CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH` if the control length is larger than the test length and `CHILD_LOOKUP`s where the node is missing on the test side.

Comment: Thanks! To fully satisfy my requirements, I need to add some logic: For `CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH` only ignore the cases where the control length is larger than the test length; and for `CHILD_LOOKUP` ignore only if control is not null and test is null. If you add this to your answer I'll accept it.